# Where to learn texture painting?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Texture painting has been really hard for me. Can anyone recommend me a nice place to learn texture painting to lighten my headache?

Comment: Really need a better description and examples of what you expect to learn to do with regards to Texture Painting. You have from Physically Based Rendering examples as Substance Painter styled realism to hand painted styles in World of Warcraft, and many different examples between them. I have my own youtube channel exploring all the many facets of painting in Blender, but it is very unconventional and I don't teach a 'style' , I teach the tools and work arounds to get things done.

Answer (score 1):

Xrg have made a very nice tutorial serie about texture painting. However it's not focused on PBR (for that you probably need to look at Substance Painter).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jR7Axe2hbz8&list=PLNHJ5gduZOiWXtbeiZZi3q082bclOHQY4
and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7ALfRw6I5I